# mac tomcat installation: Cannot find /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/bin/setclasspath.sh This file is needed to run this program

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat

I installed tomcat with brew on mac with command: brew install tomcat,

but when I tried to run the tomcat with following command:
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.28/bin/catalina run

it gives me the following error:
Cannot find /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program

In addition, when tried to install tomcat through brew, it gave me the following warnings:

Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/usr/bin/install_name_tool` with the file linked in [this article](http://www.colinfmurphy.com/how-i-fixed-homebrew-php-complier-error-with-mac-osx-10-9-update/) and then run `xcode-select --install`. Finally open XCode to accept the license.